# Can TCP send corrupted buffer?

Tags: tcp, pthreads

In my application we were sending a corrupted buffer[Got corrupted in between], with a valid length and flags=0. our send function stuck and finally because of a polling thread we cored our application.
I suspect that corrupted buffer to cause this issue, but i am not sure of the behavior.
I tried the same locally and through GDB but there was no failure or crash or thread getting stuck.

Any inputs, I am trying to prove the theory that send function struck because of corrupted buffer.

Not suspecting the remote endpoint.

Comment: Is the socket blocking? `send` will block in case there are no space to copy the application message into kernel socket buffer

Comment: Thanks,By default yes its blocking, if kernel socket buffer is the reason? any way to verify this? Does this behavior works for corrupted buffer?

Comment: Whats the OS? You can check with `netstat` utility whats the status of the socket buffer?

Comment: I have a core file with me. not the exact system.it happened on a  remote machine that is not accessible. Linux